# resize images in php with imagemagick on 1&1 hosting

Tags: php, image-processing, resize, imagemagick, gd

I am running out of memory when allowing users to resize images of modern day 12MP or higher cameras. Even some pictures that are only 900kb in size take up a lot more room in memory because it's based on pixel size (i think) so ...

I have SSH access to a 1&1 shared server and I followed their instructions to upload imagemagick and configure/make/install it into a directory on my server. Now what do I have to do in php to do the same thing as

```
$originalImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$finalImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($finalImage, $originalImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
imagejpeg($finalImage,$saveDest,$jpeg_quality);
```

the variables are hopefully self explanitory. I was trying to find my way through installing the imagick extension but i got really lost when i read about PECL and PEAR and I really don't want to screw up the working php installation somehow.

Comment: What is it you are asking? Do you need help installing the module or do you want to know if the code you posted can be run more efficiently with imagemagick?

Comment: I think my memory limit on my server is 60Mb and trying to run this code with a large image like 1920X1080 fails. I've heard imagemagick is better at handling large images so I need to know the php to use imagemagick to resize an image instead of gd

Comment: Can you install a php extension? Cause if it's not an integral part of PHP (but rather requires you to push commands to your system shell), it can get a little tricky if you're not used to that kind of stuff. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php suggests APIs like MagickWand for PHP, iMagick, and phMagick. http://www.francodacosta.com/phmagick/examples/resizing-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec('/path/to/your/home/imagemagick/installation/bin/convert '.$src.' -resize '.$newWidth.'x'.$newHeight.' '.$saveDest);
```

But make sure you have all variables coming from user site escaped. And $saveDest is writable by your webserver.

Changes are high that you run in to the same memory limit problems, couse apache/php is invoking a script which limits its memory usage to its parent.

Comment: this is close but what if i have co-ordinates set in imagecopyresampled to crop the image first?

Comment: see the imagemagick documentation, your possabilities are limitless. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Answer (score -1):

Update `php.ini` file:

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

Comment: on a shared server this will be no option.